# is Office 2003 compatible with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2003

is Office 2003 compatible with Windows 7?

Comment: See this link  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthree/archive/2009/11/19/wsj-111909.aspx

Comment: Not entirely, see e.g. [my problem here](http://superuser.com/questions/619293/office-2003-file-dialog-cant-switch-input-language-with-windows-7).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I use both at home.

Answer (score 1):

Compatible?  Microsoft says so.  But it's buggy.