# Office 2003 file dialog can't switch input language with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-office-2003, i18n

I'm using Microsoft Office 2003 (SP3) on Windows 7 (86x or 64x)

My issue is when I try to save a file, in the file selection dialog Office 2003 can't change the input language or the direction 
(neither the Alt+Shift nor Ctrl+Shift key combinations work).

When Copy-pasting a name or a path it works.

This situation happens randomly. On Windows XP I never experienced such a problem and I have not experienced this with other applications (including MS Office 2007 specifically).

What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have SP3 installed?

Comment: @Karan: Yes, of course.